# Why PS does not catch : "New-PSDrive : Logon failure: unknown user (...)"?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell module.

And within the module I handle exceptions by try...catch block. 
But for some reason when I provide WRONG password while I create New-PSDrive I get error written on the console as:

"New-PSDrive : Logon failure: unknown user (...)"

But try..catch block does not catch it and re-trhow:

```
try {
# (...)
New-PSDrive -name $myDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $sharedLocation -Credential $credentials

# (...) s
}

    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        $message = "ERROR : Occured " 

        Write-Error $message
        throw $_

    }
```

**Question:**
Any advise why I cannot catch this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is probably not a terminating error thus cannot be catched. Try using the ErrorAction parameter ti make the error a terminating error.

```
New-PSDrive -name $myDrive ... -ErrorAction Stop
```